# Request Security Function returning wrong values

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The request.security function doesn't seem to be working. I am on a daily time frame trying to request monthly closes. It works about half of the time, the other half it returns the same value as the previous value. Even get the error using the code straight from the documentation.

```
newMonth = ta.change(time("M"))

indexHighTF = barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0
indexCurrTF = barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1
nonRepaintingClose = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1M", close[indexHighTF])[indexCurrTF]
if newMonth
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(nonRepaintingClose, format.mintick), color = color.aqua)
```

Comment: What's the ticker id and can you tell us a date where there is an issue?

Comment: Multiple tickers, but was using TSLA daily chart for testing. Example date says the April close is the same as March. Both values return 207.46, yet April close is 164.31

Comment: I'm checking it with the developer team. In the meantime, I have provided another solution which seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `security()` with `lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on` and add one bar delay in your expression.

```
nonRepaintingClose = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1M", close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```